# Sending both image and data in postman via form-data fields

Tags: node.js, image, postman, sequelize.js

I'm new in node.js and I am working on a project which is made in node.js and sequelize.
How can I send both image and data in postman via body form-data?
I have searched on internet for a solution and tried them but I get an empty object.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: This link may help you.
https://www.bytescale.com/blog/postman-upload-file-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried different ways and finally solved the problem :-)

[image]

[image]